# Make a js function wait for an event listener

Tags: javascript, listener, wait

Here the problem. I have a script that collects images from the web in a "for" cycle to append them in the body. When the script links the img to its source, I introduce a script to change the source to a new one based on an event listener.

In other word, I want to wait for the event listener to go back and finish the iteration.

I was thinking to use a globar var to share the information between the listener and the script.

```
function UseNewSource(input) {  

    console.log("wait to change " + input);

    !!! wait for a listener that does not go on with the code !!!

    newSource = global_var

    return newSource
}

document.getElementById('passbtn').addEventListener('click', function () {

    console.log('clicked !!!');

    global_var = "something"

});
```

Comment: how about appending them to the body with a HTMLElementObject.className?? and later  in the event listener query those elements based on the class you set.

Comment: Just call `UseNewSource` from the event listener? The whole point of event listeners is to "wait for an event". Waiting for the event listener to fire means you transitively wait for the event. Why introduce another middlement that will "wait"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this snippet. Whenever the image is ready, the dom-manipulation code will be executed.
But it wouldn't be serially. Cause if any image that has a big size, then it will take longer time than others. But I don't think it will be an issue.
You can check the output of the console log. Thank you.

```js
const fetchImage = async (url) => {
  const img = await fetch(url).then(response => response.json());
  
  // Do the dom operation here
  console.log(img);
}

for(let i = 1; i<=10; i++) {
  fetchImage(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/${i}`);
}
```